# Spring boot load H2 db file from classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I want to package prepopulated h2 db-files with a Spring boot application. The database is only going to be used to read values.

How am I able to load the H2 files that are available on the classpath? I am very uncertain how to setup the spring.datasource.url to get this to work.

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://h2-database.66688.n3.nabble.com/Accessing-an-H2-db-file-inside-a-jar-td4022466.html You can try something like jdbc:h2:zip:~/ 
my.jar!/db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you export the schema and data into SQL scripts and use the in-memory H2 DB in combination with Spring Boot's built-in initialization feature: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

Granted, it may result in a slower startup if you have a relatively big dataset but if that were the case you probably wouldn't have put it in the JAR in the first place :)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, I tried it and it works fine. It is actually quite fast to load a considerable amount of sql on startup.